# Integration between org-transclusion and denote

Tags: org-mode

Is there a way to convince [org-transclusion](https://github.com/nobiot/org-transclusion) to accept [denote](https://protesilaos.com/emacs/denote) links as input? Or maybe a list of them? Or perhaps, in the perfect scenario, a list of them, from a dynamic block?

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it [is described on GitHub](https://github.com/nobiot/org-transclusion/issues/160): since Denote offers a function to get note's file path, the following function basically makes use of that. The code for such a function is listed below. This solves my problem just partially, since I have to manually specify the notes and I can't use dynamic blocks (to make use of keywords attached to notes), but it's still a usable in my workflow.

```
  (defun denote-org-transclusion-add (link plist)
    (when (string= "denote" (org-element-property :type link))
      (let* ((denote-id (org-element-property :path link))     ;; get denote id from denote:<denote-id> link
             (file-path (denote-get-path-by-id denote-id))     ;; path resolved by the id
             (new-link (with-temp-buffer                       ;; create a [[file:/path/to/denote/note]] org link
                         (insert "file:")                      ;; and store it in 'new-link' variable
                         (insert file-path)
                         (beginning-of-buffer)
                         (org-element-link-parser))))
        (org-transclusion-add-org-file new-link plist))))      ;; re-use the org transclusion infrastructure for file: links
  (cl-pushnew 'denote-org-transclusion-add                     ;; register the org transclusion 'plugin'
              org-transclusion-add-functions)
```

Comment: This is a link-only answer. Ideally, you should provide some detail of what the suggested solution is (possibly copying the code - with acknowledgement of course) and maybe describe how the mechanism works in a more general way, so that the solution can be applied to other types of link as well. In any case, the answer should be able to stand on its own.